# How can I make the loops fatter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, graphs

In this code, how can I make my loop fat? I know how to make it longer, but I want it wider as well. Please try to tell me using this code, and not new code. I'm new to tikZ and this is what is familiar for me.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (1) {1};
  \node[main node] (2) [left of=1] {2};
  \node[main node] (3) [right of =1] {3};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small},every loop/.style={looseness=60}]
    (1) edge [loop left] node {} (1)
         edge node {} (2)
         edge node {} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `loop left` is defined as `left, out=195, in=165, loop` (`left` is for the nodes, `loop` includes settings for `looseness`, `min distance` and the `every loop` style). So the angles are hard-coded. However you could define something like `wider loop left/.style={left, out=220, in=140, loop}`. If you want a more flexible approach, you can do that … — By the way, with `every loop/.style` you overwrite everything in that style, this is the reason why there's no arrow. Use `.append style` if you don't want to overwrite settings.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `in=<angle>`, `out=<angle>` options together with the `looseness` and/or `distance` (family of) keys. A little complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={circle,draw}]
\path
  node (1) {1}
  node (2) [left=of 1] {2}
  node (3) [right=of 1] {3};
\path
  (3) edge [out=30,in=-30,distance=3cm] (3)
  (2) edge [out=150,in=210,looseness=30] (2)
  (1) edge [out=30,in=150,looseness=10] (1)
  (1) edge [out=210,in=330,out distance=5cm,in distance=3cm] (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer?

Comment: @Alenanno I wouldn't say so; your answer doesn't mention the `distance`  jey not its variants (`out distance`, `in distance`), so besides the `looseness` option you mentioned in your answer, mine gives other possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the Tikz manual about enlarging the loop, so you might have to switch to the regular edge, and use manual `out` and `in` angles. A combination of these and `looseness` does the job.

```
(1) edge [out=150,in=210,looseness=30] (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using something like

(1) edge [loop left, very thick] node {} (1)

BTW: you should visit

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

for useful tricks

Comment: I think the question was about enlarging the loop, not thickening the edge.